# Идеология публикации npm пакетов

Tags: npm, сборка

Разрабатываю плагин к одному пакету. Получилось порядка 10 файлов с внутренними зависимостями и одна внешняя зависимость от исходного пакета. Теперь хочу этот плагин опубликовать в npm репозитории.

Вопрос: в каком виде принято публиковать пакеты с внешними зависимостями?

Сейчас все, кроме внешнего пакета, собирается в один файл при помощи `browserify`, потом, при помощи `browserify-shim` импорт внешнего пакета заменяется на обращение к глобальному объекту

```
{
 .............
 "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "chart.js": "global:Chart"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0"
  }
}
```

в итоге получается js файл полностью готовый для использования в браузере. Но перед ним нужно еще подключить `chart.js`.

Это нормальная практика? Или в npm пакете `require("chart.js")` выпиливать не нужно, а оставить это на совести сборщика, который будет подключать мой плагин к своему проекту?

Третий вариант - убрать собранный файл вообще и в пакет записывать исходные десяток файлов и конфиг сборщика `gulpfile.js`?

Comment: Оставить на совести сборщика. Собранный файл если и оставлять, то он должен быть с require без browserify - я, например, использую webpack, и самодеятельность от browserify мне совершенно ни к чему

Comment: @andreymal т.е. собирать в один файл, но внешний require оставлять. Так?